Can't find Sublime Text folder and format for special Preferences file e.g., for font change
Having a lovely time trying to find the "platform-specific" settings file referred to in Preferences.sublime-settings, so I can change the font:
// Note that the font_face and font_size are overridden in the platform
// specific settings file, for example, "Preferences (Linux).sublime-settings".
// Because of this, setting them here will have no effect: you must set them
// in your User File Preferences.
"font_face": "",
"font_size": 10,

Oh, with some studious effort I can determine where the regular Preferences file resides. (Since I can't, say, right-click in Sublime Text somewhere and select something like "Show file in Folder" to take me into Explorer and to the Preferences folder, I can't even easily find that without some acrobatics.) Now I'm looking for where or how to find or create this "platform-specific" settings, but there's no explanation here and I've already spent 10 minutes searching various keywords in two search engines. Any ideas, or should I spend another half hour of my life reinventing the wheel? I am using Windows 10.
I've already looked at this answer and it doesn't clarify.

For my system (and for posterity), I find my Preferences.sublime-settings file in:
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User
Am I supposed to put the file in there? What name must I put? Is there some template? Is this documented anywhere?

From Google search for "sublime user file preferences folder location" I've found a clue at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.htm - conceivably helpful information about the file format, but no clarity on either (1) platform-specific directory location for the file or (2) specifics on the filename format such as how to derive the  term in the filename. More troubling, there is a warning that this is for an old version and it directs me to the root (!) of the current version documentation. So, thanks much -- I get to do some more snorkeling.

After some digging, I dredged up https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/settings.html#settings-files at the path Documentation -> Settings -> Settings files, but it is as incomplete as the earlier version regarding the two questions of concern. In fact, it's substantially the same as the previous version mentioned above. I will assume I should put the file in the same directory, but I'm still baffled as to what  must be in order to actually be found when Sublime Text launches!

Google "Preferences ().sublime-settings" takes me to all the same places (including this thread!). I guessed "Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings" and found a lot of hits, top being the unofficial documentation and something at Sublime HQ.

Creating and adding the two lines to "Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings"  has no effect at all. Bizarrely, however, there is already a file named Preferences.sublime-settings in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User (aka %APPDATA%\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User). Contrary to documentation, editing that file (and NOT the -specific file) has the necessary effect of changing the settings. In fact, at least the font changes become visible the instant you change this file.

Official documentation does not appear to be helpful. For Windows, I found the user Preferences file locations at %APPDATA%\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages\User (%APPDATA% is often at C:\Users\admin\ or C:\Users<your username>), where I presume one may also create a so-called "platform-specific" Preferences file. According to unofficial documentation and a post on the forum, the correct file name, for Windows for example, would be "Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings" ("Linux" or "OSX" are other choices).
However, creating and editing a file with this name may have no effect, as was the case when I tried. Cryptically, 1 states: "This is important: Platform-specific settings files in the Packages/User folder are ignored. This way, you can be sure a single settings file overrides all the others." That suggests that there may be a different correct location to place a platform-specific file, but no documentation I've been able to find after an hour has any information as to where that file ought to be.
That said, there ought to be a "Preferences.sublime-settings" (without the platform-specific name) already in that same Packages/User directory (if not, you could try to create and modify it). In my version, apparently as a default this file contained:
{
    "font_size": 14,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Package Control",
        "Vintage",
    ],
    "theme": "auto",
}

Changing the "font_size" parameter and saving the file gave immediate gratification. Presumably, changing other values in there should yield the desired effect.
This worked for me (Stable Channel, Build 4169) on Windows 10.
